# Create a global array of objects in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I'm working on a drum pad to learn C++ programming.

I'm using a class called DrumSensor which I need to create 5 times in an array.

I'm using a header file "settings.h" to store variables I'll use throughout my code.

### settings.h

```
extern DrumSensor sensor[5];
```

### settings.cpp

```
#include "settings.h"
DrumSensor sensor[5];
```

I've been experiencing a lot with this global object array, but I've never been able to compile it.

I tried to find references such as:

[Creating Array of Objects c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24602646/creating-array-of-objects-c)

[c++ global object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918010/c-global-object)

The problem is, no matter how I try to declare my "DrumSensors", I get the following error:
... multiple definition of ...

You can take a look at the code here:
https://github.com/woodencase01/DrumSensor

Comment: This question seems to be relevant to your case, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196801/how-to-define-an-array-of-strings-of-characters-in-header-file

Comment: Please post the *minimal* code required to reproduce your problem.  comments about the author name, etc are clearly not required to reproduce your problem.  [mcve]  also, `...` is not valid c++.   You also need to post the full error message, not just part.   And in this case we need to see all your commands you're using to compile this -- somehow you're linking settings.cpp twice.

Answer (score 3):

#### About the code in your question

The way you have shown it is correct. You declared it in a header (and therefore, by extension, in any source file including that header), and defined it once in a source file.

You must be accidentally linking `settings.cpp` twice, or accidentally including `settings.cpp` somewhere, or you accidentally wrote *another* definition for this array somewhere.

---

#### About the code you pointed us to

FWIW, in the GitHub project you linked to, you do not have a `settings.cpp`, just a `settings.h` with loads of objects defined in it (i.e. without `extern`). So the problem may simply be that the code you are building is not the same code that you've been talking about.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Turns out I forgot to declare variables in the settings.cpp that were also "extern". About the Git repo, my bad, totally forgot a last push!